# header scroll inside the container

Tags: html, css

I have been looking for a solution on other questions but I am not able to make it right. I would like a div to scroll inside the container but it either doesn't work or also the header scroll inside the container:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmauceri/xSCB3/2/) ***** please look at the end for the updated jsfiddle with Jquery code

HTML:

```
<div id="my_events" class="profilePopup">
    <div class="title_background">
        <h3>My Events</h3>
    </div>

            <div id="myEventsDetails_contaner">

                <div class="myEventsIcon">
                   <div class="eventDetails">
                   <a href="">
                   <img src=""width="70px">
                   <h5><span>12-02-2014</span></h5>
                   <h5>event</h5></a>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="myEventsIcon">
                   <div class="eventDetails">
                   <a href="">
                   <img src=""width="70px">
                   <h5><span>12-02-2014</span></h5>
                   <h5>event</h5></a>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="myEventsIcon">
                   <div class="eventDetails">
                   <a href="">
                   <img src=""width="70px">
                   <h5><span>12-02-2014</span></h5>
                   <h5>event</h5></a>
                </div>
              </div>
                 <div class="myEventsIcon">
                   <div class="eventDetails">
                   <a href="">
                   <img src=""width="70px">
                   <h5><span>12-02-2014</span></h5>
                   <h5>event</h5></a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="myEventsIcon">
                   <div class="eventDetails">
                   <a href="">
                   <img src=""width="70px">
                   <h5><span>12-02-2014</span></h5>
                   <h5>event</h5></a>
                </div>
              </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myEventsDetails_contaner{
    max-height: 100%;
}
.profilePopup{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:scroll;

}
.title_background{

    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding:10px;
    position: relative;
}
.myEventsIcon{

    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.eventDetails
{

    text-align: center;
}

.eventDetails h5 span{

    color:#ff1a00;
    display: block;
}

.eventDetails a{

    width:150px;
}
```

* UPDATE JSFIDDLE WITH JQUERY CODE****************

[updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmauceri/xSCB3/8/)

Comment: check [updates](http://jsfiddle.net/xSCB3/6/)

Comment: @AtalShrivastava if  I use `position:fixed` for `.title_background` all all the popup scroll inside the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the div `title_background` out side the div `profilePopup`. And modify the css for class `title_background`  as

```
.title_background{   
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    padding:10px;
    width: 382px;
}
```

here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/U7AVL/

**My Edited code**

fiddele is  http://jsfiddle.net/epLyC/

I think this will help you...

Comment: thanks but `.profilePopup` is a popup (which is `display: none;`). It won't work If I place `.title_background` outside

Comment: i think you are looking for this only @mattia